# Android In app billing

Tags: android, product, in-app-billing

I am working on the in app billing in android and I have tested it with com.test.purchased product it and it works fine. but when i send my own product id in `requestPurchase(..)`  method which I have added and published on market. It does not show me its correct price it shows the default price which is 0.99. I have uploaded my app on market but have not published it. its in draft.

I want to know what could be the possible reason that i am not getting my product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you publish your product? And there did you set you price?

Comment: yes i have published my items and gave the prices aswell. but i have not published my application(apk). its in draft.

Comment: What is your price? maybe you put your price in some other currency and when it translate it into your home currency it displays it differently? Is google displays your product on a buying page? And is it displays the proper description for that product?

Answer (score 0):

Play store does not support draft applications for testing In App Purchases. If you want to test your in-app billing then you have to put your app in ALPHA TESTING on play store.